# Change color of checkbox input in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am fairly new to programming websites so this might be a stupid question, but I can't seem to change the color of a checkbox I have where user should accept privacy policy. The code is placed in a .PHP file.

**Code**

Here is what I have now:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="privacypolicy" value="1" tabindex="20"  onchange="jQuery('#privacypolicy').prop('disabled', false);" data-fieldblock="block<?php echo $i; ?>">
      <div class="custom-control-label mr-2"> <?php echo __("Accept","premiumpress") ?> <a href="www.site.com/privacypolicy" target="_blank"><?php echo __("<b>Privacy policy</b>","pp") ?></a> </div>
</label>
```

**What I tried**

I have been Googling for ages now and all I find is people saying to add CSS. But where would I do this? I can't just add it in html/php file, when I tried it of course didn't recognize it as code. I don't want to change some style CSS since I only want to change background color on this specific place. I can't seem to add an attribute to my  like `background-color="000000"` either.

**What I want**

Just change background color of checkbox on this specific place. I don't know if the code provided is enough, please let me know in comments if you need any more details.

Comment: You need to add style tags in your php file to use the css. Here's an link explaining this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: @Jaspal, so that is how you add CSS; thanks! I still can't seem to change the background color of the checkbox though, no code I add regarding that have any effect..

Answer (score 1):

Though it is easier than it was in the past, adding custom styling to the browsers default input fields is not as easy as it might sound. In other words, changing the color of a checkbox seems like it should be super simple but in reality you have to use quite a bit of CSS styling.  Here is a nice article that provides some examples of how to do it:
https://css-tricks.com/custom-styling-form-inputs-with-modern-css-feature

As @jaspal mentioned in his comment, you need to add css to the html output. Once you do, you can use the css styling rules in the article to target specific inputs and style them. If you are just trying to style checkboxes and not the other input types, this is a good primer: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Yeh I noticed, I thought it would be a simple attribute change within the input, why isn't it that simple? Anyway, I tried the code from the second link and it messed up my footer (made two red stripes in it) and completely removed all my input fields. The checkbox seems okay though what I can see.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `accent-color` property instead of background-color

[Full description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color)